# Selecting specific users

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a a model that stores users:

```
class SubItem(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have a group in the auth admin section called 'advisors'. How do I only show the advisors in the pulldown that django creates. (I have a feeling I have to override the **init** in forms.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out from this [link](http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/useful-form-tricks-in-django/%5D) that only selecting users in a set group needs to be enforced at the form level

```
class SubItemForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
        super(SubItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['advisor'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='advisor')
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) parameter.

Example:

```
class SubItem(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
        limit_choices_to={'group': 'advisors'})
```

Comment: do I have to re-sync my db if I make thoses changes to the model?

Comment: @Sevenearths: no need for re-syncing luckily, you can just play around with it and it should change live in the admin and modelforms.

Comment: this [http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/useful-form-tricks-in-django/] is helping me. But I still don't understand how to do it with groups

Comment: @Sevenearths: the `'groups'` part was an example, I don't know what the real name is of the field you are trying to filter by. If your other response is correct than you could use that same filter here aswell. So `{'groups__name: 'advisors'}`